# Numbers with a square sum arrangement

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

**Informal version.** For which $n>1$ can the numbers $1,\ldots, n^2$ be arranged in a square form such that the sums of the numbers in the little squares (consisting of $4$ numbers) are all equal?

**Formal version.** For any positive integer $n$ we let $[n] := \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n>1$. If $\psi:[n]\times[n]\to [n^2]$ is a bijection and $k,\ell\in[n-1]$, we let the *square sum at $k,\ell$ with respect to $\psi$* be the number $$\text{ssq}_\psi(k,\ell) = \psi(k,\ell) + \psi(k+1,\ell) + \psi(k,\ell+1) + \psi(k+1,\ell+1).$$

We say $n$ has a *square sum arrangement* if there is a bijection $\psi:[n]\times[n]\to [n^2]$ such that for all $k,k',\ell,\ell'\in[n-1]$ we have

$$\text{ssq}_\psi(k,\ell)=\text{ssq}_\psi(k',\ell').$$

**Question.** Are there infinitely many integers $n>1$ with a square sum arrangement?

Comment: Do you really mean "small (2 × 2) squares" in the informal version?

Comment: @Seva it should depend on whether we arrange numbers in integer points or in boxes.

Comment: I mean the informal version as explicitly described in the formal one :-) I hope the formal one is understandable?

Comment: @Seva I avoided the boxes vs integer points problem as mentioned by Fedor Petrov by a reformulation of the informal version. Thanks Seva and Fedor for your comments!

Comment: Can you provide an example of such an arrangement for some non-tiny $n$?

Comment: @GregMartin I thought I had an example for $n=4$, will post it if I can make it work. By the way, I haven't even be able to prove that if such an arrangement exists, then there is only one possible value for the square sums $\text{ssq}_{\ldots}$! More precisely, is it conceivable that we find some $n$ and two different bijections $\psi,\tau:[n]\times [n]→[n^2]$ that are both square sum arrangements such that $\text{ssq}_{\psi}(1,1)\neq \text{ssq}_\tau(1,1)$ ?

Comment: Of course there will be symmetries in the overall $n\times n$ square, which will lead to $8$ nominally different bijections for each arrangement.

Comment: [Most-perfect magic squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most-perfect_magic_square) are such, and they do exist as soon as $4|n$. See also [OEIS A051235](https://oeis.org/A051235).